# How to Set the Last Used On Value Manually in Programs and Features

Tags: programsandfeatures

I'm trying to figure out how (and if it is possible) I can set the `Last Used On` value for a program in Programs and Features manually.

Specifically, it's the red field in the image below. I've tried copying the format of the `Installed On` column as it is presented in the registry but that didn't set any value at all. I'm testing with Google Chrome if that makes any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft Answers discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/last-used-on-blank-on-programs-and-features/119eb9d2-6f59-441e-9f65-a8de2ee253c9):

> That feature is official[ly] deprecated and will no longer list a date. Raymond Chen wrote about it on the Microsoft Developer Network Blog...

The MVP making that statement then goes on to link to a [Raymond Chen blog posting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=38493) that discusses how Windows used to find the "Last Used" value.

> In order to get the “Last Used” and “Frequency” values, Add/Remove Programs needs to know the name of the EXE so it can ask the Start menu “Hey, how often did the user run this program, and when was the last time it happened?”

But the blog post does not address the deprecation issue.

It is likely that the deprecation portion was brought up in the comments to that post, but the comments were all lost the last time the blog was migrated. (From blogs.msdn.com to devblogs.microsoft.com.)

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739839/how-can-one-manipulate-the-start-menus-recently-used-programs-list-programmat

Comment: It's not quite clear from the answer, it is not at all possible to set that field any longer? Even outside of the regular method as described in the blog post (which I am aware was removed in Windows 7)? Like, for example, editing the registry yourself to add the information?

Comment: The DidierStevens blog entries linked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739839/how-can-one-manipulate-the-start-menus-recently-used-programs-list-programmat discuss how to read the "Last Used" info from the registry. You can presumably use the same method in reverse to set it. Please pay attention to the multiple warnings on that linked SO page that explain why it is very likely a bad idea to do this.

Comment: Thank you for point that out, I somehow missed it. I will keep those warnings in mind, I do not intended to trample over what should be left alone. I'm simply seeking a solution to my problem!